# For Crystal reports 9 for vb 6 ,during export of report , I just want to limit the user see only pdf in export combo, is there a way to do it?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

For Crystal reports 9 for visual basic 6 , you can export the report to various file format such as pdf, excel, word, rpt etc. If I just want to limit the user see only  pdf in export selected combo , is there a way to do it?

Comment: I have come to 3 solutions for this solutions 1. You have to remove the dll of particular format ex. word from your system32, if you dont want your report to be exported into this format,

Comment: the second solution is : you can use this code if you want to export your report in the partucular format ,,, for ex . pdf....<br/>With hotelvoucher.ExportOptions  <br/>
                        .FormatType = crEFTPortableDocFormat  <br/>
                        .PDFExportAllPages = True  <br/>
                        .DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile  <br/>
                        .DiskFileName = "C:\Users\kutbuddin\Desktop\export.pdf"  <br/>
                        End With  <br/>
                        hotelvoucher.Export False  <br/>

Answer (score -1):

```
Sleep 1000
Dim crapp As CRAXDRT.Application
Dim oRpt As CRAXDRT.Report


Set crapp = New CRAXDRT.Application
Set oRpt = crapp.OpenReport("E:\Income Tax\Reports\RptTotalCustomers.rpt", 1)
oRpt.ExportOptions.DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile
oRpt.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = "E:\Income Tax\dummy.xls"

oRpt.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTExcel80

oRpt.ExportOptions.ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = True
oRpt.Export False
```

Comment: @ramu : you are totally right but i dont want automatically generate the report , I just want to limit the user see only pdf in export selected combo, and when i click export button at that time only report should be generated ??